# If $H\triangleleft G$ and $H\subset K \leq G$ then $H\triangleleft K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was wondering if its true to say

> If $H\triangleleft G$ and $H\subset K\leq G$ then $H\triangleleft K$

I tried to prove it:

We need to prove that for every $k\in K$ we get $k^{-1}Hk=H $. But I'm not sure how $H\triangleleft G$ help us.

If the theorem is true, how to prove it?

Also, tried to find a previous thread but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $H\triangleleft G$ then it is true. It is enough to prove that for each $k\in K$ and $h\in H$ we have $khk^{-1}\in H$. So let $k\in K,h\in H$. But then $k\in G$ and we know that $H\triangleleft G$. Hence $khk^{-1}\in H$.